# ruby on rails javascript_include_tag :defaults

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

What the how the, where the..

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

this little evil line is pulling in 3 additional JavaScript that I could essentially give less then a damn about. In fact I would like to use that to redefine some defaults on a per page basis. However I can't seem to figure out where those defaults are defined.

Ive been on google and bing looking for answers but I yield none. I keep coming up with a document or 3 that explain using it, but not how I can use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [Rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/JavascriptTagHelpers.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag) for this.

> If the application is not using the asset pipeline, to include the default JavaScript expansion pass `:defaults` as source. By default, `:defaults` loads jQuery, and that can be overridden in config/application.rb:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(foo.js bar.js)
```

> When using `:defaults`, if an application.js file exists in public/javascripts it will be included as well at the end.

Comment: I've got jquery_ujs.js, jquery.js, application.js all auto loading. I assume based off that one little line. So am I to assume that that's like the default of the default (if that makes sense, like when nothing is configured or whatever.) I guess my end game logic when it comes to finding this out is, are these something I can turn off change, or would i be better off hardcoding javascript to my html

Comment: or better yet can I define my own :custom or :blah definition? Cause some pages I will require more then that defaults on where as others I only need the defaults

Answer (score 0):

For rails 6 may use `javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'`